# Display Dynamic added input fields and images in the same line using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, laravel

I'm trying to add dynamically input fields and when I select an element from the selected box it should show an image in the same line of the additional input fields.

So I'm using the following code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("body").on("click", ".add_new_frm_field_btn", function() {

    var random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000); //generate random values..
    var index = $(".form_field_outer").find(".form_field_outer_row").length + 1;
    console.log(index);

    //added data-index and outer..class
    $(".form_field_outer").append(
      `<div class="col-12 outer" data-index="${index}_${random}">
            <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row"> 
            <div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-2">
             <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
                <select  class="form-control maintCostField"  name="rows[${index}][id_casting]" id="id_casting" >
                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        @foreach($castings as $casting)
                          <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
                          @endforeach
                     </select>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group col-md-2"><label for="inputState">Type de contrat</label><select id="id_modele_contrat" class="form-control" name="rows[${index}][id_modele_contrat]"> <option selected>Choose...</option><option>...</option> 
                     @foreach($models_contrat as $model_contrat)
                                                   <option data-id="{{$model_contrat->id_modele_contrat}}" value="{{$model_contrat->id_modele_contrat}}">{{$model_contrat->modele_contrat}}</option>
                                                @endforeach</select></div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                            <label for="date_de_fin_du_contrat">Date de fin du contrat</label>
                            <div class="input-group date">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_premiere_diffusion" name="date_premiere_diffusion">
                                    <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon" id="spanEstPaymentDate">
                                                    <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
                                    </span> 
                            </div>
                        </div><div class="card-body "><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button></div>
        </div></div></div> `);

    $(".form_field_outer").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field:not(:first)").prop("disabled", false);
    $(".form_field_outer").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field").first().prop("disabled", true);
  });
  $("body").on("click", ".remove_node_btn_frm_field", function() {
    var index = $(this).closest(".outer").data('index')

    //get index
    $(".casting_details [data-index= " + index + "]").remove() //remove genrated casting_details2 as well
    $(this).closest(".outer").remove()
  })

  $("body").on("change", ".maintCostField", function() {
    var index = $(this).closest(".outer").data('index') //get outer div index..
    console.log(index);
    //check if the data-id not there

    if ($(".casting_details [data-index= " + index + "]").length == 0) {
      //append new...
      $(".casting_details").append(`<div data-index= "${index}" class="casting_details2"> <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-6 casting_details"> <a class="d-block position-relative" href="#"><img src="img/products/marble-cake-thumb.jpg" alt="Marble Cake" class="list-thumbnail border-0" /> <span  class="badge badge-pill badge-theme-2 position-absolute badge-top-right">NEW</span></a></div></div> `);
    }

    /*let id_casting = $(this).find("option:selected").data("id");*/
    var id_casting = $(this).find("option:selected").data("id");
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });
    $.ajax({

      url: "getCasting/" + id_casting,
      type: "GET",

      success: function(html) {
        console.log(html);

        $(".casting_details [data-index= " + index + "]").html(`<div class='d-flex flex-row mb-6'><a class='d-block position-relative' href='#'><img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/castingimages/${html.castings[0].photo} " alt='' class='list-thumbnail border-0' /> <div
                                                class="card-body align-self-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-between min-width-zero align-items-lg-center">
                                                <a href="Apps.MediaLibrary.ViewImage.html" class="w-100">
                                                    <p class="list-item-heading mb-1 truncate">${html.castings[0].nom} ${html.castings[0].prenom}</p>
                                                </a>
                                                <p class="mb-1 text-muted text-small w-100 truncate">${html.castings[0].date_naissance}</p>
                                            </div></a></div>`);

      }

    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-1 add_new_frm_field_btn">Ajouter un nouveau casting</button>
        </br>
        </br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card mb-4 form_field_outer  ">
              <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row outer" data-index="1">
                <input type="hidden" id="id_projet_casting" name="id_projet_casting" />
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
                    <select class="form-control maintCostField select2" name="rows[1][id_casting]" id="id_casting">
                      <option selected>Choose...</option>
                      @foreach($castings as $casting)
                      <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
                      @endforeach
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="inputState">Type de contrat</label>
                    <select id="id_modele_contrat" class="form-control" name="rows[1][id_modele_contrat]">
                      <option selected>Choose...</option>
                      @foreach($models_contrat as $model_contrat)
                      <option data-id="{{$model_contrat->id_modele_contrat}}" value="{{$model_contrat->id_modele_contrat}}">{{$model_contrat->modele_contrat}}</option>
                      @endforeach
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label for="date_de_fin_du_contrat">Date de fin du contrat</label>
                    <div class="input-group date">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_premiere_diffusion" name="date_premiere_diffusion">
                      <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon" id="spanEstPaymentDate">
                                            <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
                                            </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body ">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="casting_details">
                    <div class="casting_details2">
                      <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-6">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is the image is not displayed in the same line as the dynamically added input fields it is displayed shifted from the added line.

I get a result like that :

[image]

The second image is shifted from the line added with the input fields.

The problem is in my Html code, if you have any idea please help !